# using jquery slider in django -confusion about jquery-ui images location

Tags: jquery, django, image, jquery-ui

My django app has all media files in a media folder

```
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/django/myapp/media/'
...
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
```

All images are in `/home/me/django/myapp/media/img`
,sothat I can access my images by `{{MEDIA_URL}}img/myimage,png`

.Similarly ,I put the javascript files in js folder and include them like

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{MEDIA_URL}}js/jquery-1.8.3.js" ></script>
```

Likewise,all the css are in {{MEDIA_URL}}css location.

The zip file containing `jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js` comes with `jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css` and an images folder which has the images for slider etc.In my django app,

When I want to use the jquery slider, the corresponding css expects its images in an images directory.But it feels weird having an images folder inside the {{MEDIA_URL}}css directory

Can you please tell me where the `jquery-ui` images should be put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make sense to put the files in a subfolder to keep them together.

Also, Django recommends using [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) for uploaded content and [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for static site assets.

```
"{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-ui-1.9.2/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"
"{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-ui-1.9.2/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css"
"{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-ui-1.9.2/images/"
```